# Magento CE uses MD5 encryption.. How hard to upgrade to better encryption method?

Tags: magento-ce, encryption-key

Quick buffer, I know very little about encryption methods and how they are implemented, I just know a little on the quality and importance of a good versus bad encryption method. My understanding is that Magento CE uses the **very weak** MD5 encryption method, which is widely known for being lackluster and should cease even being used. Magento EE however uses SHA-256 which is know as a **much stronger** alternative.

As a two pronged question, is Magentos' thoughts on keeping CE using MD5 strictly a business decision to push vendors to EE for a stronger method?

And how hard would it be to upgrade the current method of CE from MD5 to say SHA-256 ourselves without Magento needing to implement the change for us?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento use the `getHash()` Method in the Core Helper:
`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php`

```
public function getHash($password, $salt = false)
{
    return $this->getEncryptor()->getHash($password, $salt);
}
```

If you take a look in the `getEncryptor()` Method, you will see that you can define your own Encryptor Model:

```
public function getEncryptor()
{
    if ($this->_encryptor === null) {
        $encryptionModel = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode(self::XML_PATH_ENCRYPTION_MODEL);
        if ($encryptionModel) {
            $this->_encryptor = new $encryptionModel;
        } else {
            $this->_encryptor = Mage::getModel('core/encryption');
        }

        $this->_encryptor->setHelper($this);
    }
    return $this->_encryptor;
}
```

You have to create a new xml knot `global/helpers/core/encryption_model` where you can define your own Model. And if you extend your new Encryptor Model from `Mage_Core_Model_Encryption`, you can use all Core features and just overwrite the specific Method:

```
public function hash($data)
{
    return md5($data);
}
```

I don't recommend you to change the hash Method in a Production System, because if you change the hashing Method, your existing customer can't login anymore.